# Fix GoLand not finding module dependencies ("cannot resolve...")?

Tags: go, goland, go-modules

I have installed my project's Go module dependencies with `go build`.

But GoLand is telling me it cannot resolve any of these dependencies.

How can I get GoLand to find the Go module dependencies?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Make sure that you have Go Modules support enabled.

In your preferences go to `Go > Go Modules (vgo)` and check "Enable Go Modules":

[image]

Comment: even if I downloaded all dependencies, Goland stck at 3 `go list -m xxxx` processes. when I kill the process it restart again. Why Goland need more information whe the project is build-ready.

Answer (score 5):

navigate to path project with your file "go.mod" and execute the command line

```
go clean --modcache && go mod download
```

this will download every thing again.

if was necessary, remote all require block from your go.mod with tag "// indirect" and execute command

```
go mod tidy
```

that will downlaod all sub-dependences again.

OBS: if you project path is in $PATH system, you need remove, because now the go.mod is the sufficient to replace it.

Comment: That doesn't work for my situation. Hopefully it will work for somebody, but I still have NO External Libraries, not even the header, for this one project.